# Create div-element (jQuery mobile pages) dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-mobile

When I try to add a data-role div-element dynamically in jquery it fails - it shows up but its not formatted any longer. In the html-file you can see where I put the created div-element.

What is wrong and how could I make it work?

**htlm-file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5  /jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-   1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="my_js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- jquery mobile-pages does not work here-->
<div id="mydiv">

</div>


<!-- this works just fine -->
<div data-role="collapsible">
<h4>B</h4>
<ul data-role="listview">
   <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**jquery**

```
    var string = "" +
    "<div data-role='collapsible'>" +
        "<h4>B</h4>" +
        "<ul data-role='listview'>" +
            "<li><a href='#'>Billy</a></li>" +
            "<li><a href='#'>Bob</a></li>" +
        "</ul>" +
    "</div>";
console.log(string);
$(string).appendTo("#mydiv");
```

[image]

the upper part of the image is when it's created dynamically, the lower part is what it looks like if I just put the code in the html-file. To the right you can see the string which i append to the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bind collapsible element when you add it dynamically.

Like :

```
$(string).appendTo("#mydiv");
/** Add this line and try **/
$("data-role='collapsible'").collapsible();
```

Ref Link : https://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/

Comment: tried but I get syntax error _unrecognized expression "data-role='collapsible'"_ in the console log

Comment: Can you just give id or class to your collapsible element and try binding with that? Like :  $('#mynewelem').collapsible();

Comment: When you create them dynamically, your don't need the data-role thing any more. Just give them a class and call the collabsible()-function on them:
`$( ".selector" ).collapsible()`. Ref: https://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/

Comment: I tried to wrapp a class-element around mydiv and tried with    _$(".myclass").collapsible();_ but it doesnt help